# Can typeorm validate the schema on application start?

Tags: typeorm

I know that typeorm can create the whole db schema or even synchronize the database schema with the entity definitions (see `synchronize` in [Connection Options](https://typeorm.io/#/connection-options/common-connection-options))

But in production I'd like to ask typeorm to just validate that the existing database schema matches the Entitiy definitions on application start:
e.g. if the tables, column, indizes, etc. exist

Is this possible?

Comment: I would like to be able to do this in test, to ensure all migrations where properly generated.

Answer (score 1):

You can validate for changes between the loaded schema and the current database connection. You can do this with the same methods TypeORM uses to actually synchronize because these methods are exposed.

Example:

```js
const database: DataSource = ... //connect your database

const databaseUpQueries = (await this.database.driver.createSchemaBuilder().log()).upQueries

if (databaseUpQueries.length > 0) {
  console.log(`${databaseUpQueries.length} schema differences detected in current connection.`)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

02.2021: still don't know if typeorm can do that

In the meantime, we can use [pg-structure](https://github.com/ozum/pg-structure) to implement custom checks